# How to authenticate with certificate using IbmCtgCore.dll(v9.2)with dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cics

Currently, I can run applications on cics with ibm ctg core dll.

Can I connect by ssl and **sending a certificate**? I could not find a field to add certificates to properties on **ctg core dll**. Is it possible to do this with c#?

IBM.CTG.Core.dll download link
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cics-transaction-gateway-cics-tg-sdk-downloads

Answer (score 1):

Starting with CICS TG V9.1, the programming interface for .NET programs (the classes supplied with CICS TG) support secure (SSL/TLS) connections to the CICS TG daemon.  You would use the SslGatewayConnection or SslGatewayConnectionPool class.  The SslProperties class with its ClientCertificate property (and its use of X509CertificateCollection class) provides you the ability to specify the client certificate to be passed to the CICS TG daemon for authentication.

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tg-zos/9.3.0?topic=applications-overview-programming-interface for mention of the SslGatewayConnection class and the detailed documentation for all the .NET classes and methods at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tg-zos/9.3.0?topic=core-net-framework-net-api